# Retrieve and count single occurrence of a user per bank

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to solve a certain problem I am facing. Apologies If I don't represent it the wrong way, I'm a rookie in Stackoverflow.

I have a report which is supposed gets the unique count of users, the number of accounts created, the number of accounts activated, and the number of accounts not yet activated.

I am able to get these (the number of accounts created, the number of accounts activated, and the number of accounts not yet activated), but unable to achieve the former.

Here's my script snippet.

```
SELECT Bank,Users, Added_Accounts FROM (
   select BANK_NAME as Bank, COUNT(DISTINCT USER_ID) as 'Users',
      COUNT(DISTINCT USER_ID+BANK_NAME+ACCOUNT_NUMBER) as Added_Accounts
   from MA
   where MOBILE_PROFILE_CREATION between @datefrom and @dateto 
      and USER_ID IS NOT NULL AND USER_ID !='' and Bank_Name NOT LIKE '%XXX%' 
   group by BANK_NAME

   UNION ALL

    select 'Total' as Bank, COUNT(DISTINCT USER_ID+BANK_NAME) as 'Users', 
       COUNT(DISTINCT USER_ID+BANK_NAME+ACCOUNT_NUMBER) as Added_Accounts
    from MA
    where MOBILE_PROFILE_CREATION between @datefrom and @dateto
       and USER_ID IS NOT NULL AND USER_ID !='' and Bank_Name NOT LIKE '%XXX%'

) as WeekData_UsersByBanks
```

This would get the user count per bank but what I would like to achieve is for only the first occurrence of the user to be retrieved and counted, e.g. If the user has accounts in 3 banks, I want only the first occurrence to be retrieved and counted.

Does anyone have any idea of how this can be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE

```
DDL
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MA](
    [USER_ID] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [ACCOUNT_NUMBER] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [BANK_CODE] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [BANK_NAME] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [MOBILEPROFILEACTIVE] [float] NULL,
    [MOBILE_PROFILE_CREATION] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [USERSTATUS] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO MA ([USER_ID],[ACCOUNT_NUMBER],[BANK_CODE],[BANK_NAME],    
[MOBILEPROFILEACTIVE],[MOBILE_PROFILE_CREATION],[USERSTATUS]) VALUES    
('abc@qwerty.com','009****220','63','Bank A','1','2017-08-07 00:00','N')
insert into MA ([USER_ID],[ACCOUNT_NUMBER],[BANK_CODE],[BANK_NAME],
[MOBILEPROFILEACTIVE],[MOBILE_PROFILE_CREATION],[USERSTATUS]) VALUES 
('abc@qwerty.com','005****017','63','Bank A','0','2017-08-07 00:00','N')
insert into MA ([USER_ID],[ACCOUNT_NUMBER],[BANK_CODE],[BANK_NAME],
[MOBILEPROFILEACTIVE],[MOBILE_PROFILE_CREATION],[USERSTATUS]) VALUES 
('abc@qwerty.com','007****559','63','Bank A','0','2017-08-07 00:00','N')
insert into MA ([USER_ID],[ACCOUNT_NUMBER],[BANK_CODE],[BANK_NAME],
[MOBILEPROFILEACTIVE],[MOBILE_PROFILE_CREATION],[USERSTATUS]) VALUES 
('abc@qwerty.com','302****187','76','Bank E','1','2017-08-07 00:00','N')
insert into MA ([USER_ID],[ACCOUNT_NUMBER],[BANK_CODE],[BANK_NAME],
[MOBILEPROFILEACTIVE],[MOBILE_PROFILE_CREATION],[USERSTATUS]) VALUES 
('abc@qwerty.com','207****421','33','Bank F','0','2017-08-07 00:00','N')
insert into MA ([USER_ID],[ACCOUNT_NUMBER],[BANK_CODE],[BANK_NAME],
[MOBILEPROFILEACTIVE],[MOBILE_PROFILE_CREATION],[USERSTATUS]) VALUES 
('def@ghi.com','005****047','63','Bank A','0','2017-09-09 00:00','N')
insert into MA ([USER_ID],[ACCOUNT_NUMBER],[BANK_CODE],[BANK_NAME],
[MOBILEPROFILEACTIVE],[MOBILE_PROFILE_CREATION],[USERSTATUS]) VALUES 
('def@ghi.com','237****275','50','Bank B','0','2017-09-09 00:00','N')
insert into MA ([USER_ID],[ACCOUNT_NUMBER],[BANK_CODE],[BANK_NAME],
[MOBILEPROFILEACTIVE],[MOBILE_PROFILE_CREATION],[USERSTATUS]) VALUES 
('def@ghi.com','208****712','57','Bank G','1','2017-09-09 00:00','N')
insert into MA ([USER_ID],[ACCOUNT_NUMBER],[BANK_CODE],[BANK_NAME],
[MOBILEPROFILEACTIVE],[MOBILE_PROFILE_CREATION],[USERSTATUS]) VALUES 
('poi.o@plm.com','075****022','214','Bank D','1','2017-08-03 00:00','N')
insert into MA ([USER_ID],[ACCOUNT_NUMBER],[BANK_CODE],[BANK_NAME],
[MOBILEPROFILEACTIVE],[MOBILE_PROFILE_CREATION],[USERSTATUS]) VALUES         
('qaz.wsx@mmm.com','601****999','70','Bank C','1','2017-03-15 00:00','N')  
insert into MA ([USER_ID],[ACCOUNT_NUMBER],[BANK_CODE],[BANK_NAME],
[MOBILEPROFILEACTIVE],[MOBILE_PROFILE_CREATION],[USERSTATUS]) VALUES 
('qwe@rty.com','204****889','33','Bank F','0','2017-04-21 00:00','N')
```

Here's an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6a5d4b/7) of the result I got.

In the fiddle, user abc@qwerty.com has accounts in 3 Banks (Bank A, Bank E and Bank F)

Rather than the user appearing in all Bank Counts, I would expect the user to appear in the first occurrence of the bank.

I hope this is clearer.

Comment: Could you edit your post with some DDL and consumable sample data please? Also, could you include your expected results. [How to post a T-SQL question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/)

Comment: If you try to achieve total row, consider using GROUP BY CUBE(columns_here)
This could be written without union.

Comment: @jerboy, It is still not clear what your output should look like. Could you show a dummy sample output please?

Comment: Hi @suresubs, the output is in the [link] (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6a5d4b/12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see sqlfiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6a5d4b/37/1

```
SELECT BANK
    , SUM(CASE WHEN RNUM = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Users
    , MIN(Added_Accounts) AS Added_ACCOUNTS
    , MIN(Activated_accounts) as Activated_accounts
FROM (
    select BANK_NAME as Bank
        , COUNT(ACCOUNT_NUMBER) OVER(PARTITION BY BANK_NAME) as Added_Accounts
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY USER_ID ORDER BY BANK_NAME) AS RNUM
        , SUM(MOBILEPROFILEACTIVE) OVER(PARTITION BY BANK_NAME) as Activated_Accounts

    from MA
    where MOBILE_PROFILE_CREATION between @datefrom and @dateto 
    and USER_ID IS NOT NULL AND USER_ID !='' and Bank_Name NOT LIKE '%XXX%' 

) as WeekData_UsersByBanks
GROUP BY BANK

UNION ALL
select 'Total' as Bank
    , COUNT(DISTINCT USER_ID) AS Users
    , COUNT(DISTINCT USER_ID+BANK_NAME+ACCOUNT_NUMBER) as Added_Accounts
    , SUM(MOBILEPROFILEACTIVE) 
from MA
where MOBILE_PROFILE_CREATION between @datefrom and @dateto
and USER_ID IS NOT NULL AND USER_ID !='' and Bank_Name NOT LIKE '%XXX%'
```

Comment: Thanks @suresubs. Really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how I could get the first occurrence of a user by bank. I simply used the snippet below.

```
select user_id email, min(bank_name) as bank from ma
group by user_id;
```

Here's the [SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6a5d4b/12) of the result.